# Yii2 - filter (search) gridView with hasMany viaTable join

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can I filter (search) gridView when I am using **hasMany->viaTable** relationship?

I have 3 tables - **products, components, componentsMap** (tables are populated correctly)

Products are connected with components via **componentsMap** table - structure:

```
id | component_id | product_id
```

I am using this method for connection:

```
public function getComponents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Components::className(),
        ['id' => 'component_id'])
        ->viaTable('componentsMap', ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

The search function:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Products::find();

        $this->load($params);

        $query->select(
                'products.*,
                tradeNames.name AS tradeName,
                components.name AS componentName, components.no_cas AS cas, components.no_einecs AS einecs')
            ->from('products')
            ->with(['components', 'tradeName'])
            ->leftJoin('componentsMap', 'componentsMap.product_id = products.id')
            ->leftJoin('components', 'componentsMap.component_id = components.id')
            ->leftJoin('tradeNamesMap', 'tradeNamesMap.product_id = products.id')
            ->leftJoin('tradeNames', 'tradeNamesMap.tradeName_id = tradeNames.id')
            ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'LOWER(inci)', strtolower($this->inci)])
            ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'LOWER(tradeNames.name)', strtolower($this->tradeName)])
            ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'LOWER(chemical_name)', strtolower($this->chemical_name)])
            ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'created_at', $this->created_at]);

        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'inci' => SORT_ASC,
                ]
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

In the gridView I am using this code to show components:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'componentName',
    'format'    => 'raw',
    'label'     => 'Components',
    'value'     => function($model){

        $components = $model->components;
        $i          = 1;
        $content    = "";

        foreach($components as $component):

            $content .= '<div class=product-component>';
            $content .= "<h3>Component {$i}</h3>";
            $content .= '<strong>Name:</strong> ' . $component->name . '<br>';
            $content .= '<strong>CAS:</strong> ' . $component->no_cas . '<br>';
            $content .= '<strong>EINECS:</strong> ' . $component->no_einecs . '<br>';
            $content .= '</div>';

            $i++;
        endforeach;

        return $content;

    }
```

],

Comment: You don't need the `id` field in your `componentsMap` table. Use a composite key that consists of `component_id` and `product_id`. Also, it's traditional to use singular case for model table names. For your actual question, follow [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/).